# Android tests BuildConfig field

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

Suppose my `build.gradle` file defines different values for the same variable that is defined in `BuildConfig`:

```
android {
    def INTEGER= "integer"
    def VARIABLE = "variable"
    buildTypes {
        release {
            buildConfigField BOOLEAN, VARIABLE, "1"
        }

        debug {
            buildConfigField BOOLEAN, VARIABLE, "2"
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to define `BuildConfig` value for this variable for `androidTest` (the one that is created in `app/build/generated/source/buildConfig/androidTest/debug/{app_id}/test/BuildConfig.java`)

Now, the value is the same as in `debug` closure.

> Is it possible to change it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found a way to do this [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/index.html#change_the_test_build_type)

Create another `buildType` (whose name must not start with: `test`) and pass it's name to property:

```
android {

    testBuildType "staging"

    def INTEGER= "integer"
    def VARIABLE = "variable"
    buildTypes {

        debug {
            buildConfigField BOOLEAN, VARIABLE, "2"
        }

        staging {
            initWith(buildTypes.debug)
            buildConfigField BOOLEAN, VARIABLE, "4"
        }
    }
}
```

Tests must be run against `staging` `buildType`.

Comment: And what if I don't want to create new buildType but still want to define buildConfigField only for androidTest? Creating new buildType isn't solution for me...

Comment: if your app is multi-module , you might get this error: "Unable to resolve dependency for ':currentModule@staging/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :otherModule."  to fix this, simply go to the build.gradle of otherModule and add in a staging {} entry in buildTypes.

Comment: "Tests must be run against staging buildType" - it was not clear what this meant.  I found that you need to change build variant to "staging", more info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44368130/android-testbuildtype-not-working

Answer (score 1):

The [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) equivalent of the above solution would be this:

```kotlin
android {
  buildTypes {
    create("local") {
      initWith(buildTypes["debug"])
      buildConfigField("Boolean", "IS_CI", "${System.getenv("CI") == "true"}")
      isDebuggable = true
    }
    testBuildType = "local"
  }
}
```