# android testBuildType not working

Tags: java, android, testing, gradle

```
android {
  ...
  testBuildType "deviceTest"
  buildTypes {
    debug {
      // Using 10.0.2.2 (the desktop's localhost), as the app normally runs on an Emulator
      // in debug mode.
      buildConfigField "String", "BACKEND_URL", '"http://10.0.2.2"'
      buildConfigField "Integer", "PORT", "8080"
      applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    }
    // Use local host for testing, for MockWebServer
    deviceTest {
      initWith debug
      buildConfigField "String", "BACKEND_URL", '"http://localhost"'
    }
    release {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Exactly like Google doc implies [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/index.html#change_the_test_build_type). However, this causes test dependencies (like JUnit) to be unreachable from unit tests, and so the test cannot run.

Comment: Have you tried putting `testBuildType "deviceTest"` line after `buildTypes{}` scope?

Comment: I have.. but no luck

Comment: I know it sounds like a Voodoo but can you try to use Single quotes instead of double quotes?

Comment: I love voodoos, but no luck this time :(

Comment: Did you found a solution ? If not have you try start your test from gradlew not from Android Studio ?

Comment: @OhadNavon - have you been able to figure this out? I'm struggling with exactly the same issue now :(

Comment: no solution yet

Answer (score 11):

I figured out this issue on AS 3.1.3.

The problem is Build Variant and testBuildType doesn't match. So after adding testBuildType to your gradle file, go to 'Build -> Select Build Variant' and select the same variant for your app.

You may also need set signing key or solve proguard issues before running androidTest correctly, but the dependencies should be reachable now.

More detail can be tracked here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36995546