# unable to use custom buildType - Active build variant "debug" does not have a test artifact

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-testing, android-build-type, instrumented-test

I took a look around and see some questions very similar to mine but it does appear to have the same solution I have in place which does not resolve the problem.

When I try to run a method test I receive an error in the footer of android studio that states "Active build variant "debug" does not have a test artifact"

I would like to use a different buildType for instrumented testing so that I can change an API path. It seemingly will not build and run unless I set the `testBuildType "debug"`

Here is what my gradle looks like

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    ...
    testBuildType "staging"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            manifestPlaceholders.enableCrashReporting = "false"
            manifestPlaceholders.disableAnalytics = "true"

            buildConfigField "String", "API_DOMAIN", '"https://domain/dev/"'
        }

        staging {
            initWith debug
            buildConfigField "String", "API_DOMAIN", '"/"'
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            manifestPlaceholders.enableCrashReporting = "true"
            manifestPlaceholders.disableAnalytics = "false"

            buildConfigField "String", "API_DOMAIN", '"https://domain/prod/"'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on this post. Appears that the Active Build Variant wont change on its own as one would expect.

[android testBuildType not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44368130/android-testbuildtype-not-working)